# How to make a potion with the nausea and hunger effect, and be named “Rum” using Command block in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve been making a role play map for me and my friends, the theme is pirates... so I want Rum. But I can’t figure out how to do it. I’ve googled and googled but all I’ve gotten are thing from Java edition that don’t work on PE (I’ve tried). Please help.

`give @p potion 1 8201 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Amplifier:5,Duration:1000}],display:{Name:Rum}}`

(Just of Nausea effect)

I’ve tried not adding the name part and just rename it with an anvil but it still doesn’t give me the potion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCPE does not support NBT in commands, so everything in the curly brackets is invalid syntax in PE.

An alternative solution that's commonly used, detecting the use of an item and then applying effects, also doesn't work in PE, because MCPE has no `/scoreboard` command.

You'll have to find a different way to trigger it, for example standing on a certain block type (using [`execute detect`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute), [archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1204429#execute)).

Maybe you could also retexture a throwable potion and then detect the flying potion with a command and apply the effect to the closest player.